# python working directory | set default to directory with script

Tags: python, directory, path

Suppose I write a script (say, `demo.py`), that processes a test file (say, `info.txt`). As long as I have `demo.py` and `info.txt` on the Desktop (Windows machine), script runs fine. But, as soon as I move `demo.py` and `info.txt` to some other directory, running the script throws an error saying that info.txt isn't found.

In other languages, I can set the default such that the script looking for an external file defaults to first looking in the directory the script is located in (i.e., the directory with the script is the current working directory, by default). How the heck do I get python to do the same thing? I'm not thrilled about the prospect of having to re-code the full path to files a `.py` script pulls in, if the `.py` script and the files that it pulls in are *always* in the same directory.

Comment: Add './' to your 'info.txt' so it becomes './info.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, so in order for you not to have to specify the full path name when you open a file in the same directory as the current script, you can first change the current working directory to the directory where the current script is located:

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open('info.txt') as file:
    ...
```